# Textmate 2 - Ruby not showing up as a option

Tags: ruby, macos, textmate

Here you can see my ruby bundle is defiantly installed

[image: Bundles]

And when editing text I am unable to select ruby from the list (because it doesn't exist), Is this a error with my setup or a bug in text mate? I have re-downloaded text mate and removed the settings by running

```
$ rm -rf ~/Library/Application Support/TextMate
```

[image: List available]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My bundles are located in two places. For Ruby and other bundles that come preinstalled with TextMate:

```
~/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles
```

Saved 3rd party bundles are in:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Avian/Bundles
```

Check those folders and see if you have a `Ruby.tmbundle` file.

Make sure the ruby source code file is saved with the `.rb` file extension as well, so TextMate knows to use the Ruby bundle when syntax highlighting, soft-tabbing, etc.

Comment: `/Users/oliver.atkinson/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Ruby.tmbundle` exists, and the extension with .rb doesnt add the highlighting nor the ability to run my scripts either.

Comment: well thats weird. maybe restart textmate and/or your computer. works perfectly on mine `Version 2.0-git (9294)`

Comment: Ah, I removed ruby.tmbundle and checked out the latest revision from https://github.com/textmate/ruby.tmbundle and it works.

Comment: It worked for me as well. But I wonder what made it not working all of a sudden.